# What must testers be able to do to be 'highly qualified'?

Tags: testing, testers

**Are modern testers like 'stupid' users which try to find a bug clicking and filling fields or they have solid knowledge about product cores?**

What modern testers must be able to do?

- Must they be coders creating independant/embed tests?
- Must they understand source code of products and even can fix easy bugs?
- Other things?

I'm interested in real practice.

Comment: This question feels very open ended to me. Seems like asking what a driver must be able to do to be highly qualified (driving a truck across the country is a very different skillset than driving a local delivery truck which is different than driving a racecar).

Comment: I suggest reading through and asking more focused questions on [sqa.se].

Comment: @Mike I mean, are modern testers like users which try to find a bug clicking and filling fields or they have solid knowledge about product cores.

Comment: @sergzach I fixed the link above, that site is all about  Software Testing.

Comment: @WorldEngineer Excuse me, how can I migrate the question to save internal question tracking?

Comment: @sergzach it may be a dupe but I'll ask.

Comment: SQA mod here - I think it would be on topic for SQA, the only question is if it's refined enough. I did a search and didn't find anything that really strikes me as a duplicate, but I would encourage you (sergzach) to do some searches with the keywords popping into your head. If you don't find anything, ping World Engineer with a comment (or another prog.se mod with a flag, I guess?) and have it migrated. I think the community would accept the question, its only possible downfall is being overly broad/open ended.

Answer (score 3):

A highly trained tester should have knowledge to translate specifications into testable requirements (s.m.a.r.t), so they can construct test scripts. That tester and his team should be able to verify if the product is conforming to the agreements and expectations of the client. Tne goal is to certify that the client can perform the actions for which the application is being developed.

By making testable specifications it can be determined if something works or not. By having the test scripts finished before the project, the project manager can be informed about progress, because there is a list of working and nonworking function points or nonfunctional requirements.

Testing should not be aimed at finding errors, but at defining product quality.